# Is GRE scores required before contacting potential advisors?

Tags: phd

I am from India and want to pursue a PhD in robotics/control systems and am not quite sure on how to start applying. I have my GRE about a month away from now. Is it okay to start contacting/emailing professors before I take the test?
P.S- I have a bachelors degree. I have about a year of work experience, a year and a half research experience in a lab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can contact anyone, I think. But you need to give them a reason to reply back and to consider you. I doubt that many would care, initially, about your GRE, but might want to know how you've done in relevant coursework or other research. I don't think I'd ever care about the GRE specifically, though my university might. The GRE is about your general level of knowledge, not your research potential.

But, don't send out mass emails to people along with your CV. You will be ignored. Make sure you have some knowledge of their interests and that you can speak to how your background and interests fit with theirs.

Comment: Is it okay to not have any publications at the time of emailing? I have completed a research project, to which my current advisor has asked me to write a patent. The project is currently undergoing trials to complete its productisation.

Comment: You can always contact the person. What response you get depends on their analysis. Publications are good, of course. For some, maybe essential. But not for everyone.